# Digital Clock program in C - use interrupt?

Tags: c, linux, interrupt, clock

I am writing a monitoring program for a computer cluster that displays a lot of data onto an LCD screen.  As part of the display, I would like to have a digital clock running showing the current date, hour, minute, and second.  The problem is, I have a bunch of tasks going on in a big loop (ping requests, A/D conversions, file scanning) and I just don't have time to update the clock during the loop.

I'm using C under Linux (Debian).

Any suggestions of how I should got about solving this?  I was thinking of maybe using an interrupt to update the clock every second, but how does one go about doing that under Linux?  I've only really used interrupts with microntrollers before now.

Comment: looks like you might use threads. I'm sure it is possible in C - won't be pretty, but it's possible. (and don't ask me how - I don't know. But the Linux kernel is in C and it certainly isn't all synchronous)

Comment: You can use a periodic timer using [timer_create()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html), a separate thread using [pthread_create()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), or a number of other options. You might find using threads would simplify your application logic anyhow. How do you interface to the LCD?

Comment: Thanks, all great ideas, I'll look into the threads.  I'm using SPI to talk to the LCD screen.

Comment: If there isn't time to update in the loop, will there be time to update it another way?  If the issue is updating every time through the loop, it may help to track the last time of update and only update when the time changes enough (i.e. the seconds of the day at least changes).

Comment: Why not implement a priority event loop and schedule different tasks in given period and priority, this way you can have a single thread service all your tasks according to their importance. If you don't want to stall your event loop thread you can still dispatch different routines to additional threads and have the main thread only service the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run some parallel code to do that. The best way I can think of for this application, is, by the use of threads using `pthread_create()` with a function like this:

```
void * clock_routine(void * args) {
    while(1) {
        // update clock
    }
}
```

Call it similarly to this, in your main function:

```
pthread_t clock_tid; // Clock thread handle
int rc = pthread_create(&clock_tid, NULL, clock_routine, NULL);
```

And compile the file with the `-lpthread` flag.

The code in `clock_routine` will run in parallel to your other code, and since it's only a clock, you don't have any dependency/synchronization issues to deal with.

P.S.: (Kinda useless, but here goes:) I'm not sure, but using a `sleep` function inside your `while(1)` loop, to sleep for a few microseconds, "might" improve your program, since you don't need "real" time clock update, but just a few microseconds of accuracy. Constantly updating the clock like this, "might" be considered busy-waiting. If anyone knows more on this, please, correct me.